# swift 3 SKAction speed property

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I tried to change the speed property of a SKAction Animation. I have a few menu buttons with little image clips (from short video clips). Now I want to change the speed of this clips. First I tried to change the timePerSeconds of the animate SKAction, now I found there's an speed property on the SKAction itself.

But nothing, speed = 0.0 should stop the animation, I tried it with the animate or the repeatforever part. any ideas?

```
// all anim sequences in an array
var mainAktionArray = [SKAction()]


let menuAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: menuFrames, timePerFrame: frameTime )
let runForEver = SKAction.repeatForever(menuAnimation)
mainActionArray.append(runForEver)
menu.run(runForEver)


func setFrameRate(wert : Float32){

 menuSpeed = CGFloat(wert)
 menuSpeed = 0.0

 for el in mainActionArray {
     el.speed = menuSpeed
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the run command, the action inside of it is copied to the node, it is not a reference. Actions are immutable objects to allow it to safely be used across multiple nodes. This allows you to use 1 action variable across many nodes.

You need to pull the actions out of your node if you want to set a specific speed.  To do this you need to assign it a key, by doing `menu.run(runForEver,withKey"runForEver")`, then you can extract it with `let action = menu.action(forKey:"runForEver")` then set `action.speed = 0`

Comment: ok, I didn't need to put the actions in an array, amazing. thanxs!